# Batch script to silently install Office365.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, office365, silent

I have assembled a batch script to silently install office 365 using the following:

```
"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\apps\company1\office.exe" /S
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. How can I get around this error?

The office.exe is in the right location the CMD window just opens then instantly closes when run as admin.

Sorry for my limited knowledge on this matter.

Comment: add Pause at the next line of your script, run as admin, and see if what's shown helps you solve, if not, post it here.

Comment: What error?  You have not shown us any error message!

Comment: I thought you had to create a deployment package/xml configuration for `setup.exe`. Are you sure that running something called `office.exe` with an `/S` option is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ways to fix this:

- Is this the right installation path?

Is this the correct installation path? As in if you double click it will launch the install wizard?

- Try the 'start' function

Try this:

```
start "" "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\apps\company1\office.exe" /S
```

other than that I have no clue whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

adding `@echo off > nul` will make it run silently